# LED glows brighter instead of turning off

Tags: c, led

I am reading a status word that consists of 24 bits, and want the LED to change corresponding to the value of the bit. I want the LED to fully turn off, but sometimes instead of turning off it gets brighter.

I am using a simple pin toggle function to toggle the led

```
nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_2);
```

Is it possible that the LED value resets to 0 but acctually stays on, making the LED brighter?

Comment: Off-topic: Do you have a pull down resistor between the LED and ground?

Comment: Yes, i have a 1k resistor before the led.

Comment: What LED, what system, what context? What are you even talking about?

Comment: @Unimportant Why would a pull resistor do anything? It's gonna be an output. Do you mean series resistor?

Comment: @Lundin it's within the realm of possibility that I have no idea what I am talking about.

Comment: @Unimportant Ok :) (This would be why we post these kind of questions at https://electronics.stackexchange.com and include a schematic!)

Comment: It is a regular 2V red LED, i am working on the lead-off detection of my ECG PCB. When a electrode isn't connected correctly, the resistance will go up toggling a bit which i want to see using the led.

Comment: Okay thanks then i'll go there, I thought this was a software related issue

Comment: If you only toggle the bit, how could you be sure to set it to 0 to switch LED off? Do you count how many time you toggle? Could anyone else call toggle function? Does the toggle function return some state? Nearly all inportant information is missing.

Answer (score 0):

If it gets brighter, then before it was dimmer.  To dim an LED, one usually uses pulse-width modulation, which means the LED is being turned on and off very quickly.

The following is speculation ...

If the LED, as part of the PWM process, happens to be in the off state when you try to toggle it, then it will be turned on and the PWM operation (which might be managed for you by a library or interrupt handler) will be canceled.  Thus you see the LED at full brightness, which it brighter than it was.